# Unit Testing a Trigger

Tags: unit-test, force.com, ide

Here is the piece of code for a trigger that I need to break into unit tests.  I was thinking that I could begin by testing the most further in if statements as one unit test and make an additional unit for each if statement moving further out.  Does this approach makes sense?

```
Trigger BuildComponentBI on Build_Component__c(before insert , before update) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
        double q = 0;
        for (Build_Component__c C: Trigger.new) {
            if (C.Manual_Override__c == False){

                List<Effort_Matrix__c> em = Effort_Matrix__c.getall().values();

                q = c.Scale__c;

                For(Effort_Matrix__c e:em){
                    if(e.Component_Name__c == c.Type__c){
                        if(e.Phase__c == 'Build'){
                            c.Estimated_Build_Hours__c = e.OOM__c * q;
                        }
                        if(e.phase__c == 'Analysis'){
                                c.Estimated_Analysis_Hours__c = e.OOM__c * q;
                            }
                        if(e.phase__c == 'SIT'){
                                c.Estimated_SIT_Hours__c = e.OOM__c * q;
                            }
                        if(e.phase__c == 'Deployment'){
                                c.Estimated_Deployment_Hours__c = e.OOM__c * q;
                            }
                        if(e.phase__c == 'UAT'){
                                c.Estimated_UAT_Hours__c = e.OOM__c * q;
                            }
                        if(e.phase__c == 'Unit Test'){
                                c.Estimated_Unit_Test_Hours__c = e.OOM__c * q;
                            }
                        if(e.phase__c == 'Design'){
                                c.Estimated_Design_Hours__c = e.OOM__c * q;
                            }
                        else{}
                }
              }     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start testing from the outer if statements and then go deeper in. Also you can make your life easier if you rewrite those if statements to something like:

```
Map <String, String> phaseToField = new Map <String, String> ();
phaseToField.put('Build', 'Estimated_Build_Hours__c');
phaseToField.put('Analysis', 'Estimated_Analysis_Hours__c');
phaseToField.put('SIT', 'Estimated_SIT_Hours__c');
phaseToField.put('Deployment', 'Estimated_Deployment_Hours__c');
phaseToField.put('UAT', 'Estimated_UAT_Hours__c');
phaseToField.put('Unit Test', 'Estimated_Unit_Test_Hours__c');
phaseToField.put('Design', 'Estimated_Design_Hours__c');


For(Effort_Matrix__c e : em)
{
    // I guess it's decimal or integer
    Double oom = e.OOM__c * q;

    if(e.Component_Name__c == c.Type__c)
    {
        sObject eRecord = e;
        sObject cRecord = c;

        if (phaseToField.get((String)eRecord.get('Phase__c')) != null)
        {
            cRecord.put(phaseToField.get((String)eRecord.get('Phase__c')), oom);
        }
    }
}
```

It's easier to maintain and to scale, and will also not have any impact on your test classes.

Comment: What does the the Map function do?
What does the phaseToField.put function do?

Comment: More on the Map class - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm and sObjects - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Comment: So this is my first unit test I've ever been tasked with writing.  For the block of code below, would it make sense to create a new test method called compTypeTest, create 2 new class, create and instance of them and set them equal to eachother.  Total rookie here, gonna have to hold my hand.  Thank you so much.
if(e.Component_Name__c == c.Type__c)